# Installing/Using Pillow on Python 3.6 and Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-imaging-library

Alright, I need some pointers. I am missing something. I am trying to use Pillow through Python 3.6. The platform I use is Visual Studio 2017. I can't get it to work.

I downloaded Pillow from this website:
https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/
And ran the installer.

According to my research, I need pip to install it; which comes built-in python 3.6. I have seen sign that it is actually installed through my module in visual studio (pip 9.0.3). I simply need to use the following line:

> from pip.commands import install

and also tried

> import pip

Now, according to this:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/installation.html
All I have to do is

> pip install Pillow

Though other sites indicate that PIL is still being used. I have tried both without success. Pillow is not recognized and a error comes in: invalid syntax.

I am clearly doing something wrong. I consulted some youtube tutorial; they all skip that part. They download then go straight to their coding platform and it works. 
 I can only guess I have additional steps to do with Visual Studio.
Also... The location of my files might be out of whack due to IT security on my work laptop. Could that be an issue?

Comment: I usually just install modules through command prompt `py -m pip install Pillow`, after Pillow is installed it is imported as `import PIL`

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
python -m pip install pillow
```

No need to downloade Pillow from the website.

After that, to use it you can do:

```
import PIL
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback. I played with Visual Studio some more; there is a way of getting it straight from the menu.

I opened a Python 3.6 project/solution. On the "Python Environment" node in the solution explorer, I right clicked and created a virtual Python environment.

Then I right clicked on the virtual environment and selected "Install Python Package...".
You can then search the package you need for your project.

I don't know if this is the most efficient way. From my research, I think the package are only applicable to my virtual environment; I still have to test that out to make sure.

I may have gone the long way around, but writing the proposed code did not work out. I am sure it works, but I am thinking I might not be using it in the right location.

Anyway, thanks for the help!